# Avoid self-closing tags in cheerio

Tags: cheerio

is there a way to avoid self-closing tags in `cheerio` (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) in the latest `1.0.0-rc.10.` version.

Instead of `<div class="adContainer"/>` I need `<div class="adContainer"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using selfClosingTags: false.

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(content, {
  xmlMode: true,
  selfClosingTags: false
});
```